# I am not able to install nodemon package

Tags: nodemon

Not able to install nodemon package, here are the error messages.

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/atulyadav/.npm/_logs/2021-08-31T18_23_33_532Z-debug.log
(base) atulyadav@ATULs-MacBook-Pro my-express-server %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things

1. change the permission of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder or
2. Try `sudo npm install nodemon - g`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo npm install nodemon -g` , this should resolve the issue.

Note : It will prompt you to enter your password, you might not see the "letters" you are typing, but keep on typing and hit enter.